# EF Code First Integer Discriminator Column

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

According to this source

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx

it should be possible to have the TPH discriminator column be an integer:

> Also, changing the data type of discriminator column is interesting.
>   In the above code, we passed strings to HasValue method but this
>   method has been defined to accepts a type of object:
>
> public void HasValue(object value);
>
> Therefore, if for example we pass a value of type int to it then Code
>   First not only use our desired values (i.e. 1 & 2) in the
>   discriminator column but also **changes the column type to be (INT, NOT
>   NULL)**:
>
> modelBuilder.Entity()
>               .Map(m => m.Requires("BillingDetailType").HasValue(1))
>               .Map(m => m.Requires("BillingDetailType").HasValue(2));

However, when I do that in my code I see discriminator values like "1" and "2", but the column type is still

> nvarchar(128), not null

Is it in fact possible to specify an integer discriminator column?  If so, how?

I'm certain that I specify my mapping as *.HasValue(1)* and not *.HasValue("1")*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<X>()
    .Map<X>(m => { m.Requires("BillingDetailType").HasValue(0).HasColumnType("tinyint"); })
    .Map<Y>(m => { m.Requires("BillingDetailType").HasValue(1); m.MapInheritedProperties(); })
    .Map<Z>(m => { m.Requires("BillingDetailType").HasValue(2); m.MapInheritedProperties(); })
    ;
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to include some kind of explanation and/or commentary along with your code.